# python read & check file first line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find files to add CopyRigth block.
So, I write this:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".cs"):
           try:
               content = open(root + "\\" + file, "rt", encoding="utf-8").readlines()[0]
               if not content.startswith("#region Copy"):
                   print(content)
                   print(content.startswith("#region Copy"))
                   print(root + "\\" + file)
           except Exception as e:
               pass
```

Works, but if comment `print(content)`, then it prints all files names

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".cs"):
           try:
               content = open(root + "\\" + file, "rt", encoding="utf-8").readlines()[0]
               if not content.startswith("#region Copy"):
                   # print(content)
                   print(content.startswith("#region Copy"))
                   print(root + "\\" + file)
           except Exception as e:
               pass
```

There is a reason for this magic?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to accomplish with this code. Can you add a few lines explaining the purpose of it, and how it fails to fulfill that purpose?

Comment: That's weird. It should only print the names of files whose first lines do not start with "#region Copy". BTW, it'd make it easier for other people to test your code if you used `os.path.join(root, file)` to join root to file, as recommended in the os.path docs, rather than `root + "\\" + file`, which doesn't work on non-Microsoft systems. Also, why are you doing `.readlines()[0]`? If you only need the first line of a file you should get it using `.readline()`. Using `.readlines()[0]` means your program has to read the whole file into memory.

Comment: thanks for  `.readline()`, I missed this method. And it's weird, because I just need list of files to do some work.